# App to populate Firebase with external data source

Tags: firebase

Maybe OT for a Firebase discussion but what app structure is the most efficient way to populate a Firebase database with a data source which has an api access facility? This is a project to use data from a city's open data portal which has api access. I have a demo OS X app doing this but maybe there is a better way for a background app to periodically gather the city data and populate FB. Like with other open data portals, I do not have access to the city's server

Comment: A few thoughts; First is that Firebase may or may not be supporting OS X any longer, so I would not spend too much time on Firebase OS X development until that's been resolved (!!!!). Second is that Firebase is an awesome solution to store that kind of data. Last thing is that without knowing anything about the existing data, it would be difficult to suggest a Firebase structure.  Oh, and this is a perfect use case for leveraging Firebase on OS X to handle this kind of task. It would NOT be good on an iPhone.

Comment: So the app I'm developing has an iOS component which interfaces with Firebase and that works great - I just need to find the most efficient/scaleable way to periodically populate and update FB with the new civic JSON data from the http api calls other than through an OS X app running in the background. Ideally the api calls would be through an app running on a PaaS rather than a single machine, which would then POST the updated data to FB.

Comment: Interesting model! You will obviously need a device that supports one of the Firebase API's so would think getting a used Mac or a Mac mini and running it headless would work well for that task - craft an app to pull the data down, massage it and post it to Firebase.

Comment: Yes - this is what I have working now in a development environment - I just want to move away from having the app on a Mac to a more robust setup for production, and a PaaS service seems the way to go.